# Why does UpdateView need to have model/queryset/get_queryset defined when using form_class as opposed to CreateView?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

Works like a charm:

```
MyCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = "my_template_name"
    form_class = MyModelForm
    success_url = "/success/"
```

But the following doesn't:

```
MyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = "my_template_name"
    form_class = MyModelForm
    success_url = "/success/"
```

I get this error:

```
MyUpdateView is missing a queryset. Define MyUpdateView.model, MyUpdateView.queryset, or override MyUpdateView.get_queryset().
```

Why does an `UpdateView` need `model`, `queryset` or `get_queryset` defined to not cause an error while `CreateView` doesn't? Shouldn't it be able to automatically derive it from the Model used in the ModelForm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently (django 1.5.1 official release) `UpdateView` is calling `self.get_object()` to be able to provide `instance` object to Form.

From https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5c2/django/views/generic/edit.py#L217:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return super(BaseUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And `self.get_object` method needs one of this properties declared: `model`, `queryset` or `get_queryset`

Whereas `CreateView` don't call `self.get_object()`.

From https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5c2/django/views/generic/edit.py#L194:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    return super(BaseCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have a problem in your urls.py file.

What I think you wrote in it is:

`url(r'foldername/(?P[0-9]+)/$', views.UpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),`

but you have to change UpdateView to MyUpdateView, like this:
`url(r'foldername/(?P[0-9]+)/$', views.MyUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),`