# 'UpdateView with a ModelForm as form_class'-issue

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-forms

The code I would like to get is for a page that has a simple form of one field to change a user's email address using an `UpdateView`.

Sounds simple, but the difficulty is that **I want the URL mapping `url(r'email/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', EmailView.as_view(),)` not to use the `id` of the Model used in my ModelForm (`User`) but the `id` of another Model (`Profile`).**

The `id` of a `Profile` instance of a specific user can be called as follows inside a view: `self.user.get_profile().id`. I am using the `Profile` model of the reusable app [userena](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena) if you are wondering.

A (afaik not optimally implemented ¹) feature of an `UpdateView` is that [if you want to use your own  ModelForm instead of letting the `UpdateView` derive a form from a Model you need to(otherwise produces an Error) define either `model`, `queryset` or `get_queryset`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613398/why-does-updateview-need-to-have-model-queryset-get-queryset-defined-when-using).

So for my `EmailView` case I did the following:

**forms.py**

```
class EmailModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
          "email",
        )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print self.instance
        # returns <Profile: Billy Bob's Profile> instead of <User: Billy Bob> !!!
        return super(EmailModelForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```
class EmailView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile # Note that this is not the Model used in EmailModelForm!
    form_class = EmailModelForm
    template_name = 'email.html'
    success_url = '/succes/'
```

I then went to `/email/2/`. That is the email form of the `user` that has a `profile` with `id` `2`.

If I would run a debugger inside `EmailView` I get this:

```
>>> self.user.id
1

>>> profile = self.user.get_profile()
>>> profile.id
2
```

So far so good. But **when I submit the form it won't save. I could overwrite the `save` method in the `EmailModelForm` but I'd rather override something in my `EmailView`. How can I do that?**

¹ Because `UpdateView` could just derive the model class from the ModelForm passed to the `form_class` attribute in case it is a ModelForm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having your view and model form correspond to different models seems a bad idea to me.

I would set `model = User` in your `EmailView`, then override [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) so that it returns the user corresponding to the given profile id.

Comment: Indeed, thank you so much. When I used `get_object` I didn't even need to set the `model` attribute